# Is it possible to create a query in Cypher with this regular expression (a.b)* ? a and b are relationships between two Nodes

Tags: regex, cypher, match

I know it's possible to create in Cypher a Query with path matching. You can concatenate relationships between Nodes like: (n)-[REL_TYPE1]->()-[REL_TYPE2]->(m) which will be as regex a.b where a is equal to REL_TYPE1 and b is REL_TYPE2.

Is it possible to create a query between the two nodes where the relationships are nested like in this regex: (a.b)* ?

I also read the Cypher doc but don't find a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very abstract. Let me see if I can make it more concrete.

A Cypher path pattern like `(n)-[:A]->()-[:B]->(m)` is similar to the regex `nm` in that `n` must be followed by `m`.

You want to know if it is possible in Cypher to do something similar to the regex `(nm)*`. In other words, you want to find paths in which the `A`/`B` sequence repeats any number of times (including 0).

Here is one way:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[:A|B*0..]->(m)
WITH p, RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rs
WHERE
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(rs)-1, 2) WHERE TYPE(rs[i]) = 'A') AND
  ALL(j IN RANGE(1, SIZE(rs)-1, 2) WHERE TYPE(rs[j]) = 'B')
RETURN p
```

Alternatively, you can use the APOC library's [apoc.path.expandConfig](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/) procedure to find repeating sequences of relationships, which may be more efficient.